# redirect with www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If I open mysite.com then this redirects me on www.mysite.com. This is OK.
But if I open mysite.com/admin then this redirect me on www.mysite.com instead of www.mysite.com/admin

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Should do the trick. Use the parentheses `()` to match a pattern then a `$1` backreference to put it back into the new URL.

Edit, thinking about it, similarly you could just change the ^ character (the match on clause) to a . in your original pattern which should do the same as above.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I suspect you have some other rule breaking it then? Do you have RewriteEngine On somewhere above those lines?

Comment: Also, perhaps you could post your entire code if you're still having trouble. I'd also recommend http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ for testing- it might help explain where you're going wrong. This tester, and a live site I tested it on works using the above two rules.

Comment: please update your question with your entire htacess file so I can help you further

Comment: Just tried it again now that I'm back at a computer- http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/9576/htaccess.jpg works OK for me.

Comment: The second solution works for me. The first one neglected to add a directory if it was present. For example: `http://example.com/somedirectory/foobar.html` would redirect to `http://www.example.com/foobar.html`, which didn't exist